# Determine assembly framework without loading it

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm writing a C# console application which must run under .NET Framework 2.0, but needs to be able to identify an assembly's framework version, even if it's higher than .NET 2.0.

I can't use `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName` or related functions because they will throw a `BadImageFormatException` if the target assembly was built under a later framework version. Is there some way to get this information without attempting to load the assembly in any way?

Note: I know that this is possible using PowerShell, but that tool is not available in the target environment.

Please note also that I do not need to find out the version of the assembly, but the version of the Framework it requires.

Comment: Incorrect. That is the version of the assembly itself, not the version of the framework it was compiled against.

Answer (score 0):

All right, while `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` will choke on the wrong Framework, I found a way to do this by reading the assembly as a byte array and then analyzing it using ReflectionOnlyLoad.

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(tgtAssembly);
int asmLength = fs.Length > int.MaxValue ? int.MaxValue : (int)fs.Length;
byte[] buffer = new byte[asmLength];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, asmLength);
Assembly asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(buffer);
string frameworkVer = asm.ImageRuntimeVersion;
```